# Как сделать JS prompt, чтобы находился в input'e

Tags: javascript, html

```js
    function validate(){

    var log=new Array(),
        pas=new Array(),
        login_ok = false,
        user_name,
        password;

    log[0]="login1";
    log[1]="login2";
    pas[0]="pass1";
    pas[1]="pass2";

    user_name = prompt("Логин","")||"";
    user_name = user_name.toLowerCase();
    password = prompt("Пароль","")||"";
    password = password.toLowerCase();
    if (user_name== log[0] && password== pas[0]) {
     login_ok=true;
     window.location="/test.html";
    }
    if (user_name== log[1] && password== pas[1]) {
     login_ok=true;
     window.location="/test.html";
    }

    if (login_ok==false) {alert("Неверный логин или пароль!")};
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div align="center">
     <form>
      <input type="button" value="Войти на сайт" onClick="validate()">
     </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Есть валидация, как из `prompt` можно сделать `input`? Например `<input class="login">` и `<input class="pass">`, и кнопка войти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user_name = document.querySelector(".login").value;
password = document.querySelector(".pass").value;

<button type="button" onclick="validate()">войти</button>
```

Comment: про querySelector вообще забыл, спасибо

Comment: @АндрейЗахаров Пожалуйста. Успехов!